# Change color/text of QProgressBar on mouse over filled bar

Tags: c++, qt

How is it possible to change the color and/or text(format) of a `QProgressBar` if the mouse is over the filled part of the bar?

I have stacked multiple `QProgressBar`s on top of each other, each showing more content than the previous.

I want to highlight the biggest bar still under the mouse on mouseover and show some bar-specific text. However, the bars are the same size and therefore I want to recognize the filled area of the bar.

[image]

E.g., if the mouse is over the third bar, I want to highlight the part from the left to the third bar and show text specific to the third bar.

This is the code I use for the stacked ProgressBars:

```
class MultiProgressBar : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MultiProgressBar( QWidget* parent = Q_NULLPTR ) : QWidget( parent ), layout( new QStackedLayout( this ) )
    {
        layout->setMargin( 0 );
        layout->setStackingMode( QStackedLayout::StackAll );
    }

    void insertBar( QColor const& color )
    {
        auto bar = new QProgressBar();
        bar->setTextVisible( false );
        bar->setRange( 0, 10000 );

        QPalette palette = this->palette();
        palette.setColor( QPalette::Highlight, QColor( color.red(), color.green(), color.blue(), 100 ) );
        palette.setColor( QPalette::Base, QColor( color.red(), color.green(), color.blue(), 0 ) );
        bar->setPalette( palette );

        layout->addWidget( bar );
        progress_bars.push_back( bar );
    }

public slots:
    void setValues( const std::vector< int >& values, const std::vector< std::string >& names )
    {
        if ( values.size() < progress_bars.size() )
        {
            for ( auto* widget : progress_bars )
            {
                layout->removeWidget( widget );
            }
            progress_bars.clear();
        }
        while ( progress_bars.size() < values.size() )
        {
            insertBar( QColor( 0x46, 0xA1, 0xD9, 255 ) );
        }

        for ( auto i = 0; i < progress_bars.size(); ++i )
        {
            progress_bars[ i ]->setValue( values[ i ] );
            // progress_bars[ i ]->setFormat( QString::fromStdString( names[ i ] ) );
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector< QProgressBar* > progress_bars;
    QStackedLayout* layout;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) To change color of filled area you can set new color to the palette of progressbar like this:

```
QPalette newPalette = bar.palette();
newPalette.setColor(QPalette::Highlight, "red"); // setting color to red
bar.setPalette(newPalette);
```

2.1) Assign text to progressbar you can with `void setFormat(const QString &format);` function like in your commented string

```
progress_bars[ i ]->setFormat( QString::fromStdString( names[ i ] ) );
```

2.2) Get this text you can by calling `QProgressBar::text()` function;

3) If you want to highlight specific progressbars you can reimplement

```
QWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
```

in which you can calculate margins of filled area:

```
void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e){
    highlightProgressBars(e->pos()); // passing position of mouse cursor
}
```

**NOTE**: Don't forget to enable mouse tracking for progressbars and your `MultiProgressBar` widget:

```
bar->setMouseTracking(true);
```

4) Function below gets position of mouse in parameter. It highlights area from left to pointed progressbar inclusively and shows in console text assigned to highlighted progressbars through `format` property

```
void highlightProgressBars(QPoint point){
    int widthOfBar = ((QProgressBar*)progress_bars.at(0))->width();
    int valueForPoint = 10000 / widthOfBar; // value of progressbar for width==1
    for (auto pb = this->progress_bars.begin(); pb != this->progress_bars.end(); ++pb) { // iterating vector to paint progressbars
        int leftMargin = 0; // "left margin" of current progressbar is in fact right margin of filled area of previous progressbar
        if(pb != this->progress_bars.begin()){ // except first progressbar in vector which doesn't have previous progressbar
            --pb; // get previous progressbar
            leftMargin = ((QProgressBar*)*pb)->value() / valueForPoint; // get width of filled area
            ++pb; // return to current progressbar
        }

        if(leftMargin < point.x()) { // if position of cursor is to the right of "left margin" of current progressbar we highlight it
            QPalette newPal = ((QProgressBar*)*pb)->palette();  //getting palette
            newPal.setColor(QPalette::Highlight,"red"); // and setting color of filled area
            ((QProgressBar*)*pb)->setPalette(newPal); // finally setting palette to widget
            qDebug() << ((QProgressBar*)*pb)->text(); // show text of highlighted progressbar in console
        }
        else{ // if not we highlight it another way
            QPalette newPal = ((QProgressBar*)*pb)->palette();
            newPal.setColor(QPalette::Highlight,"lightblue");
            ((QProgressBar*)*pb)->setPalette(newPal);
        }

    }
}
```

If you want to highlight only one progressbar you should change in code above this:

```
if(leftMargin < point.x()) {
```

to:

```
int rightMargin = ((QProgressBar*)*pb)->value() / valueForPoint;
if(leftMargin < point.x() && point.x() < rightMargin) {
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I especially like the detailled breakdown and comments!